# Content Approval: how to stop micro changes to be again approved

Tags: content-approval

Once a document is approved, after a change it again asks for approval. My requirement is once document is approved it should stay approved even when user changes it. I'm not using versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Event Receiver, and check whether it was previously approved, or not. If so, then you can approve it automatically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it in more detail ...how to create event reciever

Comment: How to create event receivers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx